# Returning clients with post request using WebClient

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an API documentation. My goal using this doc make a post request to retrieve clients from external api using WebClient. Here the example of the request:

```
url: "https//:anyurl.com"
{
  "command": "getClients"
}
```

Here how the response looks like:

```
{
    "available": true,
    "data": [
        {
           
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Some description",
            "date": "date",
        },
        {
         
            "id": "2",
            "name": "SomeName",
            "date": "date",

        }
    ]
}
```

Here how I did by now:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
WebClient client = WebClient.create();
MultiValueMap<String, String> bodyValues = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
bodyValues.add("command", "getClients");

    WebClient.ResponseSpec response = client.post()
            .uri(new URI("https//:anyurl.com"))
            .header("token", "myToken") //I have a header as well
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(bodyValues))
            .retrieve();


    System.out.println(response);
}
```

The response class:

```
public class ClientList {

    
    private Boolean available;
    private List<Clients> data;

}


@Document(collection = "clients")
public class Clients {

    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp date;

//getters and setters
}
```

By now it returns nothing. Is there any solution?

Comment: Do you have a class representing the response? Additionally, can you include the complete code of the method making the call?

Comment: @JoãoDias Added classes. By now I am doing this in pure Java, so no methods are called.

Comment: What do you mean? You have a java method where you have `WebClient.ResponseSpec response = client.post()` right? Can you please include the complete method and class? Thanks.

Comment: No, I am doing this on main() class

Comment: Ok, then add the complete main class, please. Thanks.

Comment: @JoãoDias Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try the following? I am guessing that your `Mono` was not being subscribed and thus the request was never completed.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create();
        RequestDto requestBody = RequestDto("getClients");

        client.post()
            .uri(new URI("https//:anyurl.com"))
            .header("token", "myToken") //I have a header as well
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(requestBody)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ClientList.class)
            .subscribe(response -> System.out.println(response));
    }
}
```

Assuming you have DTO classes as follows:

```java
public class RequestDto {
    private String command;
    private RequestDataDto data;

    // constructor, getter , setter
}

public class RequestDataDto {
    private int start;
    private int finish;

    // constructor, getter , setter
}
```

Comment: Still getting null values

Comment: I guess that `body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(bodyValues))` is not doing exactly what you think. It returns a BodyInserters.FormInserter to write the given MultiValueMap as URL-encoded form data, which is not JSON as I assume the API is expecting.

Comment: Don't know, however I followed doc. Is there analogue for Json then?

Comment: It says, that RequestDto need to be cast to (MultiValueMap<String, String>). I assume there is some problem with RequestDto class. And I need to pass both command and getClients like Json.  The RequestDto class  just create a command

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please check the edited answer ;)  "getClients" is the value associated with "command" in the JSON and it is also the value of the attribute ´command´ in  `RequestDto`. When it is serialized to JSON the one that you need will be generated.

Comment: How I will know that its returning smt? Right now the programm just starting and finishing without displaying anything except some system descriptions.

Comment: Have you updated your code with the most recent version of the code in my answer? If yes, and it does not work, have you debugged your application?

Comment: I added block() instead of subscribe and now it works. By the way, what if I wanna pass another parameter like "id": "123". Should I create another RequestDto then? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: If you just want to add a parameter in addition to `command`, then you just need to add such an attribute to `RequestDto`.

Comment: Sayin i have this kind of body:  {"command": "getClients", data: { "start": "1", "finish": "10"}} Struggling with data inner json. Should I create a List<String> data? And how then I can create new RequestDto?

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check it. In upcoming topics, please create a new question instead of adding new requirements to an already answered question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sending `json` is the default way for `webclient`, so all you need to do is to pass in the body correctly.
here are the ways:

```
.body(Mono.just(data))
```

or:

```
.body(BodyInserters.fromValue(data))
```

Comment: What kind of data should I pass to Mono? Like Json ?  Or how my value can be pass to Mono?

Comment: @AlexWhite You can send json data if you want to have a json content type header

Comment: But Mono needs object, not Json